# Lithium cells sorter for battery assembly

Tags: c++, sorting

I need to sort vector on N subvectors (or segment original vector on blocks) with k length and as much as possible equal sum of "blocks".

P.S. I know about sites like repackr.com, but i need this code for my coursework, and unfortunately i cant change the subject. You can say that I'm a lazy man, but I've been doing this algorithm for 2 weeks now, and I haven't achieved the desired result. I haven't found any similar realisation of this algorithm on stackoverflow or internet at all.

Example input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Example INCORRECT output:

9 1 5 (Total:15 Diff:0)

8 2 6 (Total:16 Diff:1)

7 3 4 (Total:14 Diff:-1)

Example CORRECT output:

9 1 5 (Total:15 Diff:0)

7 2 6 (Total:15 Diff:0)

8 3 4 (Total:15 Diff:0)

Example of incorrect code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class cells {
    vector <double> cellsCap; //List of cell capacities
    vector <double> blockSum; //Block capacity
    vector <double> blockDiff; //The difference is relative to the average capacity
    int S, P; //S - In Series P - In Parallel
public:
    void Cellsfinput(const string& fname) { //File input
        ifstream fin;
        fin.open(fname);
        double intmp;

        while (fin >> intmp) {
            cellsCap.push_back(intmp);
        }
        fin.close();
    }

    void SPinput(const int& Sinp, const int& Pinp) { //S, P input for Cellsfinput.
        S = Sinp;
        P = Pinp;
        for (int i = 0; i < S; ++i) blockSum.push_back(0);
    }

    void Cellsconsinput(vector <double> cellsCapinp, const int& Sinp, const int& Pinp) { //Input from arguments
        S = Sinp;
        P = Pinp;

        for (int i = 0; i < S * P; ++i) cellsCap.push_back(cellsCapinp[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i < S; ++i) blockSum.push_back(0);
    }

    void Cellsfoutput(const string& fname) { //File output

        ofstream fout;
        fout.open(fname);

        double tmp;

        for (int i = 0; i < S; ++i) {
            fout << "Block№" << i + 1 << " ";
            tmp = 0;
            for (int k = i; k < cellsCap.size(); k += S) {
                tmp += cellsCap[k];
                fout << cellsCap[k] << ' ';

            }
            fout << "Total:" << tmp << " Diff:" << blockDiff[i] << endl;
        }

        fout.close();
    }

    void Cellsconsoutput() { //Console output
        double tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < S; ++i) {
            cout << "Block№№" << i + 1 << " ";
            tmp = 0;
            for (int k = i; k < cellsCap.size(); k += S) {
                tmp += cellsCap[k];
                cout << cellsCap[k] << ' ';

            }
            cout << "Total:" << tmp << " Diff:" << blockDiff[i] << endl;
        }
    } 

    void sortcells() {
        sort(cellsCap.rbegin(), cellsCap.rend());

    vector <double> sortedVec; //Assembled, sorted (at the end) vector
    double midCap; //Average capacity of blocks in an assembly
        long double midTmp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < S * P; ++i) midTmp += cellsCap[i]; //midCap calculation
        midCap = midTmp / S;

        for (int i = P; i > 0; --i) { //Iterating through blocks
            for (int k = 0; k < S; ++k) { //Iterating through the elements in the block
                if (i == P) { //Initial filling with maximum elements (controversial decision)
                    sortedVec.push_back(cellsCap[0]);
                    blockSum[k] += cellsCap[0];
                    cellsCap.erase(cellsCap.begin());
                    continue;
                }
                for (int j = cellsCap.size() - 1; j >= 0; --j) { //Iterating over elements for parallels
                    if (j == 0) { //If there is no suitable cell, it takes the largest
                        sortedVec.push_back(cellsCap[0]);
                        blockSum[k] += cellsCap[0];
                        cellsCap.erase(cellsCap.begin());
                        break;
                    }
                    if (blockSum[k] + cellsCap[j] >= midCap / i) { //The main logic of selection takes the first element in the block that +- coincides with the average value for this "vertical".
                        sortedVec.push_back(cellsCap[j]);
                        blockSum[k] += cellsCap[j];
                        cellsCap.erase(cellsCap.begin() + j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cellsCap = sortedVec;

        for (int i = 0; i < S; ++i) blockDiff.push_back(blockSum[i] - midCap);

        /*int tmp, minDiffa, minDiffb; //Bad code
        for (int i = 0; i < S; ++i) {
            for (int k = i; k < cellsCap.size(); k += S) {
                for (int j = S - 1; j > i; --j) {
                    for (int t = j; t < cellsCap.size(); t += S) {
                        if (abs(blockDiff[i] + (cellsCap[k] - cellsCap[t])) < abs(blockDiff[i]) && abs(blockDiff[j] + (cellsCap[t] - cellsCap[j])) < abs(blockDiff[j])) {
                            cout << endl << "k:" << k << " t:" << t << " K-T: " << cellsCap[k] - cellsCap[t] << " K:" << cellsCap[k] << " T:" << cellsCap[t] << endl;
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } */
} 
};

int main() {
    cells block;
    block.Cellsfinput("123.txt "); //Input
    block.SPinput(3, 3); //Input S (serial connection) and P (parallel connection)
    block.sortcells(); //Sorting
    block.Cellsfoutput("1234.txt "); //Output
}
```

Comment: seems a lot like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning

Comment: My apologies on [the last ask of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72409442/lithium-cells-sorting-algorithm). Once it was fixed up and made answerable, I clicked the wrong link and cast the last delete vote instead of voting to re-open. I've raised a flag, but the Mod review queue is a deep son of a <expletive deleted>.

Comment: @AlanBirtles,Thank you for identifying the algorithm.

Comment: @user4581301,everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

To find the best solution you have to pretty much try all the combinations.

Optimizations on the full exhaustive search:

1. The largest charge is always in bin 0, others will be just permutations of the bins.
2. If a bin already has `charge >= avg` taking any more can only make things worse.
3. The last bin always gets all unused charges.
4. `throw Perfect()` when all bins have avg charge, can't improve on that.
5. Abort recursion when error so far exceeds best error.

Optimization not used:

6. If a bin skipped a charge `c1` then it should only recurse to the next bin if `charge + c1 > avg`.

It might make sense to sort charges in descending order so each bin fills up quickly and maybe gets lucky with a perfect fit early. I didn't bother. With the given input it uses up all the smallest charges first and then lower in the search tree there are fewer options. Worst case you may have to test every combination and the very last one is the best solution. So I'm unsure if sorting is even improving the search time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

class Perfect { };

void dosolve(const std::vector<double> &charges,
             std::vector<int> &bins,
             int num_bins,
             double avg,
             int bin,
             size_t index,
             double charge,
             double error,
             double &best_error,
             std::vector<int> &best) {
    if (bin + 1 == num_bins) {
        // last bin takes all remaining cells
        for (size_t i = 0; i < charges.size(); ++i) {
            if (bins.at(i) == -1) {
                charge += charges.at(i);
            }
        }
        error += abs(avg - charge);
        if (error < best_error) {
            best_error = error;
            best = bins;
            // take charges for real
            for (size_t i = 0; i < charges.size(); ++i) {
                if (best.at(i) == -1) {
                    best.at(i) = bin;
                }
            }
            if (error == 0) throw Perfect();
        }
        return;
    }
    if ((charge >= avg) || (index >= charges.size())) {
        // bin has no more charges to take, next bin
        error += std::abs(avg - charge);
        if (error < best_error) dosolve(charges, bins, num_bins, avg, bin + 1, 0, 0, error, best_error, best);
    } else {
        if (bins.at(index) == -1) {
            // take charge
            bins.at(index) = bin;
            dosolve(charges, bins, num_bins, avg, bin, index + 1, charge + charges.at(index), error, best_error, best);
            bins.at(index) = -1;
        }
        // skip charge
        dosolve(charges, bins, num_bins, avg, bin, index + 1, charge, error, best_error, best);
    }

}

std::vector<int> solve(const std::vector<double> charges, int num_bins) {
    std::vector<int> bins(charges.size(), -1);
    std::vector<int> best;
    const double total = std::accumulate(charges.begin(), charges.end(), 0);
    std::cout << "Solving for " << num_bins << ": avg = " << total / num_bins << std::endl;
    double best_error = total * (num_bins - 1) + 1; // larger than one bin taking all charges
    // largest charge goes into bin 0
    size_t max_index = 0;
    size_t max_charge = charges.at(0);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < charges.size(); ++i) {
        if (charges.at(i) > max_charge) {
            max_index = i;
            max_charge = charges.at(i);
        }
    }
    bins.at(max_index) = 0;
    // search all combinations and catch a perfect solution
    try {
        dosolve(charges, bins, num_bins, total / num_bins, 0, 0, max_charge, 0, best_error, best);
    } catch (Perfect&) { }
    return best;
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<double> charges{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    const int NUM_BINS = 3;
    const std::vector<int> bins = solve(charges, NUM_BINS);
    for (int bin = 0; bin < NUM_BINS; ++bin) {
        std::cout << bin << ":";
        double charge = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < charges.size(); ++i) {
            if (bins.at(i) == bin) {
                std::cout << " " << charges.at(i);
                charge += charges.at(i);
            }
        }
        std::cout << " : " << charge << std::endl;
    }
}
```